# Trying to find a duplicate version of PHP on my system. Where is it?

Tags: php, apache-http-server, version

I have having a *helluva* time trying to track down which php binary my apache is using.

`locate bin/php` returns this list

```
/usr/bin/php
/usr/bin/php-cgi
/usr/bin/php-config
/usr/bin/phpize
/usr/local/bin/php
/usr/local/bin/php-cgi
/usr/local/bin/php-config
/usr/local/bin/php-shell.sh
/usr/local/bin/phpize
```

Let's see the versions:

```
/usr/bin/php -v       shows 5.3.2
/usr/bin/local/php -v shows 5.3.2
```

What about `which`?

```
[macek ~]$ which php
/usr/bin/php
```

### The problem

`phpinfo();` when executed by apache shows **5.2.11**

Where is this phantom 5.2.11 on my system?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @Daniel Beck, yes, see the solution below. Apache is loading php as a module. Replace this module with an updated one and you should be all set :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using PHP through CGI?  Or did you build it into Apache at runtime as mod_php?  If you're not running PHP as a CGI program, it doesn't matter where it is in the shell.

Comment: Ah! I'm pretty sure it's loading as `LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`

Answer (score 1):

Check and make sure your apache install isn't loading mod_php from two different places. In a lot of modern linux distributions, Mod_php is included under `/etc/http/conf.d/php.conf`, and not (as used to be the case) in the regular `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file.

I've seen people accidentally tell apache to load php twice, not knowing that. It's especially common if you build your own version of php, and update the httpd.conf file yourself, without checking to make sure there *isn't* a php.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure, you can see what's actually running in your apache.

Two ways I know of:

The `lsof` command lists open files, and you can specify a process ID, and it will show the files open (including shared libs) for that process.

Once opened, shared libs are mapped into memory. On Linux you can look in the /proc/pid/maps file to see all shared libs mapped for your process.